# Clock synchronization over SignalR in IIS stops suddenly

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, signalr, serilog, webapi

Our ASP.NET Core application has a hosted service running on Quartz; its job is to emit the current datetime every single second through SignalR, so that all connected users have a synchronized clock. This task is very important since our application deals with realtime auction negotiations and we need the users to have a synchronized clock to perform any operations on the application. Anytime after the datetime is emitted, a Serilog trace log is written.

The problem is the following: Lately the application users have been experiencing a situation where the application clock stops emitting values and the front-end clock stops receiving any time synchronization messages for a while. We have checked the application logs and no exceptions have been thrown, however, we have observed the log stops writing for a while (around 1 to 2 minutes). When the incident is over, all the SignalR messages that weren't sent during that time are suddenly sent in less than a second and the corresponding logs are written.

https://i.postimg.cc/KvMY5mvY/image.png

(In the attached image you can see the time mismatch between the message sent through SignalR and the one written in the log.)

P.D. The application is hosted on IIS 7 and Windows Server 2012.

We have searched everything and even checked the infrastructure settings, however, nothing seems to be off.

Comment: While SignalR is aiming for realtime applications like yours, it is not trivial to configure it and all dependencies (like hardware/networking) to achieve certain level of performance. Azure SignalR service has seven Standard tiers for different performance capabilities, https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-performance and even with that there can be latency on 1 percent of the messages. Your own SignalR setup might be harder to achieve the same. To see further into this issue, you might contact Microsoft Support to learn more.